# Center responsive absolutely positioned element with fixed margins

Tags: html, css, centering, absolute

I have an absolutely positioned CSS banner that has a responsive width and height based on viewport size. The element is centered on desktop and tablet devices, but not on mobile (when the banner's width starts to shrink).

I can't use the classic `margin: 0 auto;` trick because the margins have to be set to a fixed value for the banner to work.

The code is below:

HTML:

`<h1 class="banner">A Simple CSS Banner</h1>`

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rye);

body 
{ background: #eee; }

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 100px -200px;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 150px);
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #8a1;
  font: normal 30px/60px 'Rye';
  text-align: center;
  color: #451;
  background: #9b2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,.15) inset,
    0 6px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.banner::before,
.banner::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -70px;
  top: 24px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 30px solid #9b2;
  border-right: 20px solid #791;
  border-bottom-color: #94b81e;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.banner::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -70px;
  border-left: 20px solid #791;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

@media (max-width: 475px) {

  .banner {
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 45px;
  }

  .banner::before,
  .banner::after {
    border-width: 45px;
    border-right-width: 30px;
  }

  .banner::after {
    border-left-width: 30px;
    border-right-width: 45px;
  }

}
```

Link to working codepen: https://codepen.io/Adam0410/pen/QZOKdV

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your example doesn’t make it clear why this would have to be absolutely positioned in the first place.

Comment: Have you tested it on your phone or have you just resized your browser window?

Comment: @misorude it has to be absolutely positioned so the ::before and :after pseudo-elements can be positioned relative to it

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: _“it has to be absolutely positioned so the ::before and :after pseudo-elements can be positioned relative to it”_ - no, for that to work it only has to be _positioned_ - `position:relative` would be enough for that.

Comment: @misorude How would `position: relative` help in centering the element?

Comment: In that you _can_ simply use auto margins for that again …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps you.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rye);

body {
  background: #eee;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  display: block;
  margin: 100px 0;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 150px);
  min-height: 60px;
}
.banner span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid #8a1;
  font: normal 30px/60px "Rye";
  text-align: center;
  color: #451;
  background: #9b2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.banner::before,
.banner::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -70px;
  bottom: -24px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 30px solid #9b2;
  border-right: 20px solid #791;
  border-bottom-color: #94b81e;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.banner::after {
  left: auto;
  right: -70px;
  border-left: 20px solid #791;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

@media (max-width: 475px) {
  .banner {
    min-height: 90px;
    line-height: 45px;
  }

  .banner::before,
  .banner::after {
    border-width: 45px;
    border-right-width: 30px;
  }

  .banner::after {
    border-left-width: 30px;
    border-right-width: 45px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="banner"><span>A Simple CSS Banner</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you keep the top and bottom margin:

```
left: 0; right: 0;
margin: 100px auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Media queries and adapt Width and margin.

something like:

```
media (max-width: 475px) {
  .banner{
    width: 200px; 
    margin:100px -100px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to center an absolute or fixed element you should :

```
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  right:0%;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: As I said I can't use `margin: 0 auto;` in this case, please read the question